# EC2 instance inaccessible sometimes

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I am facing a weird but yet real situation, I try to assemble best words to describe the problem.

I have an EC2 instance which is an alias to www.example.com using Route53. I noticed that it stops working sometimes - if I browser my domain www.example.com it gives me `www.example.com's server IP address could not be found.` error (regardless of what type of browser I switch between or use private window), at the same time, if I access the website from some other computer it works, after 15 or 20 minutes I can access my domain on my machine again but again it stops working after some time and this loop continues.

I am unable to understand this behaviour.

Comment: Can you do series of the same dig command so e.g dig a www.example.com see if on any the response changes, disappears or the status is listed as servfail for example

Comment: Check that all four of the Route 53 nameservers you've set for the domain are the ones Amazon gave you. I've seen sometimes people make a typo in one of the four, which results in exactly this.

Comment: @TimothyFrew everything is good with dig.

Comment: @ceejayoz I have deleted and re decalred the Nameserver and so far so good from last 4 hours :)

Comment: @Adnan Cool! Glad that helped.